# How to set TextSearch.Text for a combobox whose TextBlock uses converter?

Tags: wpf, combobox

In the below code, Combobox is wired to NameInfo object along with a converter.NameInfoConverter returns a format in which items in combobox are shown in a particular format (for eg: LastName, FirstName (Badge#) )

Now, when I set TextSearch.Text="{Binding NameInfo, Converter={StaticResource NameInfoConverter}, ConverterParameter=true}" on combobox; TextSearch doesn't work. When I set TextSearch.TextPath="Name", search itself works but doesnot get the correct format displayed in the selectionbox of combobox.

Any Ideas?

```
<StackPanel>
    <ComboBox x:Name:"cmbName">
        <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name, 
        Converter={StaticResource NameInfoConverter}, ConverterParameter=true}"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ComboBox>
</StackPanel>
```

Answer (score 1):

You've probably hit a limitation in the API. I suggest you take an alternative route and bind directly to a property that is correctly formatted for your textblock.

If this is a serious app, you may want to look into using the [MVVM pattern](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx) and place your converted/formatted property in the viewmodel. Otherwise, just create a new property on your databound class called `NameInfo` or something and do the conversion from that.